# Steps Of Control Creation Process WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have been searching for such an explaination for a while and I couldn't have found any yet. The thing is that I would like to know the steps of initialization/creation process of a Wpf Control.

Lets take a simple Button and I would like to know what is happening when constructor gets called, when is the control added to visualTree/logicalTree, when does invocation of dependencyproperty values happen, when is ApplyTemplate() called?

I need this information to be able to write proper custom control and I think it will help others too in case they wonder why this.Template.FindName("test") always returns "null" when being called inside a constructor of a control.

Can anyone answer this or provide me with links of tutorials where the concept of initizaling a control is poperly explained?

Thanks :)

Comment: Install the .NET Framework source available from here.... http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx ... then you can debug to your heart's content

Comment: @colinsmith thanks for that suggestion but debugging source code will confuse me even more because its overwhelming

Comment: Try this as a starting point.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: i just read that article. its not helping me much.

Comment: There are two nice books: Pro WPF in C# 2010 - MacDonald, WPF Control Development Unleashed - Podila. It is worth reading them both.
Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746975/302677)

> **Sequence of events when a Window is created and shown**
>
> As requested, here is the sequence of major events in WPF when a
>   window is created and shown:
>
> 1. Constructors and getters/setters are called as objects are created, including PropertyChangedCallback, ValidationCallback, etc on the
>      objects being updated and any objects that inherit from them
> 2. As each element gets added to a visual or logical tree its Intialized event is fired, which causes Styles and Triggers to be
>      found applied in addition to any element-specific initialization you
>      may define  [note: Initialized event not fired for leaves in a logical
>      tree if there is no PresentationSource (eg Window) at its root]
> 3. The window and all non-collapsed Visuals on it are Measured, which causes an ApplyTemplate at each Control, which causes additional
>      object tree construction including more constructors and
>      getters/setters
> 4. The window and all non-collapsed Visuals on it are Arranged
> 5. The window and its descendants (both logical and visual) receive a Loaded event
> 6. Any data bindings that failed when they were first set are retried
> 7. The window and its descendants are given an opportunity to render their content visually
>
> Steps 1-2 are done when the Window is created, whether or not it is
>   shown.  The other steps generally don't happen until a Window is
>   shown, but they can happen earlier if triggered manually.

Also, I personally found the [DispatcherPriority Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) useful in determining the event order in some cases

- Invalid
- Inactive
- SystemIdle
- ApplicationIdle
- ContextIdle
- Background
- Input
- **Loaded**
- **Render**
- **DataBind**
- **Normal** - Constructors run here
- Send

Comment: Hi Rachel, i still dont know when exactly should i do what at what step of initialization. for example i have a customcontrol that holds a property and 4 levels deeper there is a visual element that should get the value of that property. how and when do i message the visualElement that the property has been set. i dont want to use depenendecyproperty and bind through relativeSource, i also cant use FineName in ApplyTemplate because the customControl's ContentTemplate is composed together on initialization. So at what step and how do i solve this?

Comment: @cyberist Perhaps you can edit your question (or create a new SO question) with a small sample of your code demonstrating your problem? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but perhaps the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is what you're looking for?

Comment: its too much code. which part of the example didnt you get? its a customcontrol called "MyCustomControl" and it has its ControlTemplate. Inside the ControlTemplate there is a Button that has its custom ControlTemplate. In that Template there is an element that needs the value of a property that MyCustonControl owns. How do i do that? At what step of initializatin do i give the value?

Comment: @cyberist Well ideally I'd do that sort of thing with a binding, but if you want to do it in the code behind you can probably do it in the `Loaded` event, since that runs after `Render`

Comment: it should have be done before rendering even before measure override.. what step of initialization is that?

Comment: @cyberist Since it's in a Template, it won't get rendered until the control using the template gets rendered, so I don't think you can do it before then. It might be possible to find the Template in the Resources and modify it from the code-behind, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I'll figure something out.