# Troubleshooting Win8 Apps: When are my XAML-defined Page fields initialized?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8

I'm trying the MVVM pattern and I've run into a problem.

Here's how I instantiate my model:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    ...
    ...(omitted boiler plate generated lines here)
    ...
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <common:LayoutAwarePage.DataContext>
        <local:TextGameClientModel x:Name="textGameClientModel"/>
    </common:LayoutAwarePage.DataContext>
```

But when I try to use it, I get a *NullReferenceException* because *this.textGameClientModel* is NULL:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.textGameClientModel.runsPublished += textGameClientModel_runsPublished;
}
```

I've also tried the same line in the Page's *OnNavigateTo* handler, and also in the *OnLoaded* handler, but with the same result.

**Where is the right place to hook up my event handler?**

(Please don't let my code-behind in an MVVM project distract you from the question.  My use of a RichTextBox has forced me to color outside the lines a little.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote an answer about the [WPF Creation Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13861398/302677) fairly recently, however that's not the problem in this case.

In this case, you are setting the `DataContext` in your XAML, however that's not the same as setting the `textGameClientModel` property

You need to do something like this to set the property equal to your `DataContext` first

```
this.textGameClientModel = this.DataContext as GameClientModel;
```

or simply cast your `DataContext` as your class to setup the event

```
((GameClientModel)this.DataContext).runsPublished += textGameClientModel_runsPublished;
```

As a side note, I never recommend hardcoding the `DataContext` into a `UserControl` like you have. By doing so, you are preventing any other `DataContext` from getting passed to the `UserControl`, which kind of defeats one of the biggest advantages of WPF/MVVM, which is having separate UI and data layers.

Comment: Well I don't entirely get it, but it certainly works.  Thanks very much!  :)

Comment: @BigScary The `DataContext` is the data layer that is behind your UI layer, which is usually referenced by the UI layer when you do a binding. I actually have a post on my blog that explains exactly what the `DataContext` is in simple terms. [What is this “DataContext” you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/tag/wpf-datacontext/) You may find useful if you're new to WPF :)